# Click and LongClick Listener throw IllegalStateException

Tags: java, android, exception, button, onclicklistener

Im getting this error when trying to implement both `onClickListener` and `onLongClickListener` for a `RelativeLayout`:

```
10-19 17:49:31.400: E/AndroidRuntime(30886): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-19 17:49:31.400: E/AndroidRuntime(30886): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

This is part of the code:

```
RelativeLayout meals_layout = (RelativeLayout) view
.findViewById(R.id.meals);      

meals_layout.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() { 
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                JournalActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle(R.string.meal_delete); 
        builder.setView(clickView);

        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.string_delete,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            }

        });
        builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.string_cancel,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                    int which) {
                // Do nothing
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        builder.create().show();
        return false;
    }
});

meals_layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                JournalActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle(R.string.meal_edit); // al que hacerlo bonito
        builder.setView(clickView);

        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.string_edit,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        }
    });

        builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.string_cancel,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                    int which) {
                // Do nothing
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });


        builder.create().show();

}
});
```

The first time I open the activity, I can do a longclick as many times as i want. But when I click any other other button (not only the one sentenced here), if I try again to do a longclick... the application crashes.

I will really appreciate your help. 
Thanks :)

Comment: Are you doing this in your `onCreate()` or your `onResume()`?

Comment: in a separated method but it is called from onCreate()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each view is only allowed one parent. Apparently `clickView` already has one, so when you call `setView(clickView)` it throws the error. One fix is to add:

```
((GroupView) clickView.getParent()).removeView(clickView);
```

to the beginning of both of your listeners. This will "orphan" `clickView` so it can be added to the AlertDialog.

Comment: `((GroupView) clickView.getParent()).removeView(clickView)` with try/catch it works perfectly.